# Префикс "/ru" в адресе сайта

Tags: .htaccess, apache, веб-программирование, url

Нужно добавить для сайта префикс:

> /ru

чтобы было:

> site.com/ru/

ну и все остальные ссылки соответственно, чтобы были так же с ним:

> site.com/ru/url1
>
> site.com/ru/url2

Сейчас используя .htacces имеется строка

```
RewriteRule ^ru/(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Она позволяет обращаться к файлам через префикс /ru, однако главная страница вызывается только без префикса, а при попытке обратится как

> site.com/ru/

отдает 404

Comment: Уточняйте подробности для более скорого получения ответа.